# Query of more than one table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I want to retrieve info from more than 1 table.

I have tried to look into using the ViewModel but do not fully understand how to implement it.

My Model is setup using ADO.Net framework.

If you could point me to any resources that could help me understand this it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these

[Link 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/01/using-viewmodel-information-in-an-asp-net-mvc-2-editor-or-display-template.aspx)

[Link 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/02/01/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications.aspx)

[Link 3](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)